# DAX Difference between columns in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: excel, dax, powerpivot

I'am struggling with a DAX measure (or calculated column maybe?)  for getting the difference between 2 columns in a one-to-many relationship.

Here's an example

A table contains required activities divided in tasks (task 1 and task 2).

Another table is fullfilled with employees who work part of their time on the different tasks.

I am asked to provide the difference between the task required times (in required_activities table) and actual times (in employee table)

data model:

[image]

tables:

[image]

So I would like to get a Pivot table like this one:

[image]

How to build the measure for calculating the `difference (employee real times - required_activities times)`? I tried using `RELATED` function but can't make it work.

Comment: Before giving you a full answer - I appreciate the above is a sample, but will there always be task 1 and task 2? As it is currently, you either need to re-shape your data model, or have an extra table. I can provide an answer for either depending on that there will only ever be a 'task 1' and a 'task 2'.

Comment: @Sam Thanks for your comment. Well, as far as I know today, there will even always be at least a 'task 3' in both tables. It's even more complicated (according to my DAX level) as there are task 1..task 3 in year N and year N+2, but let's start with a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two methods, Method 1 will get you going faster but is limited - whereas Method 2 needs a little effort to shape your data.
Method 1 answers your question directly.
Method 2 is the recommended approach.

---

#### Method 1

If there are a smallish, finite number of tasks then try the following:
Add a new table to your data model. Let's call it `task` that looks like:

| Task |
| --- |
| task 1 |
| task 2 |
| task 3 |

Single column table with a row for each of your task's name. No relationship needed.

Next, add these three measures to your model.

```
required:=
  var task1 = SUM(required_activites[task 1])
  var task2 = SUM(required_activites[task 2])
  var task3 = SUM(required_activites[task 3])
  RETURN SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('task'[Task]),
    "task 1", task1,
    "task 2", task2,
    "task 3", task3,
    task1 + task2 + task3
  )

real:=
  var task1 = SUM(employees[task 1])
  var task2 = SUM(employees[task 2])
  var task3 = SUM(employees[task 3])
  RETURN SWITCH( SELECTEDVALUE('task'[Task]),
    "task 1", task1,
    "task 2", task2,
    "task 3", task3,
    task1 + task2 + task3
  )

diff:= [real] - [required]
```

**Updated**

> Note: If your version of Excel doesn't support `SELECTEDVALUE` then
> replace it with:

```
   RETURN SWITCH( IF( HASONEVALUE('task'[Task]), VALUES('task'[Task]) ) ,
```

And that should do it. Ensure you are adding `'task'[Task]` in your Pivot table Rows.

---

#### Method 2

The other method requires altering the shape of your data model and you will need to use Power Query to do this. This method is the recommended approach as it will scale and perform optimally. (Lookup 'Star schema')

For both of your tables, select all the task columns and unpivot them so you get a structure like this:

| activity id | Task | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | task 1 | 0.5 |
| a | task 2 | 0.5 |
| b | task 1 | 0.2 |
| b | task 2 | 0.3 |

**Updated**

> While in PowerQuery, select your `required_activities` query/table
> (the one that you've unpivoted), right-click and `Duplicate`. Rename
> this new query to `Dim Activity`.
>
> - Right-click on the `activity id` column header, and select `Remove Other Columns`.
> - And one more time, right-click on the column header and select    `Remove Duplicates`
>
> Again, select your `required_activities` query/table, right-click and
> `Duplicate`. Rename this new query to `Dim Task`. Follow the same
> steps so that you are left with a Task column without duplicates.
> (Note, this step removes the need for the earlier `task` table
> mentioned in Method 1.
>
> In your Data Model (Power Pivot), create relationships like so:
> [image]

Once you have that, the DAX measures become super simple:

```
required:= SUM(required_activites[Value])

real:=SUM(employees[Value])

diff:= [real] - [required]
```

**Updated**

> In your Pivots and Charts, use `Dim Activity` & `Dim Task` for your rows/columns etc...
> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Thanks again. I have Office-2019, so no `SELECTEDVALUE` AFAIK. I used `VALUES` instead, no error, but not sure the semantics is the same. Unfortunately I cannot set measures into Pivot table values Field. As for **Method 2**, I don't understand why I need the task table. What are the required relastionship? I tried to create required_activities --- employees on activity id, but both columns contain duplicated values. I don't understand how to create relationship along with task! Why does `SUM()` work? I would have expected something using `SUMX(...FILTER() )` or `GROUPBY` task.

Comment: I have updated the answer above, lookout for the highlighted **Updated** sections. Method 1, I've provided an alternative to `SELECTEDVALUE`. Method 2, added additional steps needed in PowerQuery, and relationships. Measures stay the same. `SUM()` works because your model is shaped correctly, visuals/tables will apply the correct context filtering (row/column). Method 2 is recommended, you can have new tasks added without needing to change anything. If you do have other columns in your tables, then move them into the Dim tables, possibly create a Dim Employee table.

Comment: Thanks so much for your efforts, kind explanations and screen copies.  Cannot try now but wil try as soon as possible. I am much more at ease with Power Query, DAX is hard for me, but seems the right tool here.

Comment: Thanks again. Your solution works perfectly. Is a common and sound practice to extract `Dimension tables in any case?

Comment: It is. Lookup "Star Schema" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/star-schema